# net surgery on a custom caffe model

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I'm trying to modify the weights of a caffemodel which is part of a caffe-branch called Deep Lab. Although there is a tutorial on [how to do net surgery](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb), when I try to do the same with my custom caffemodel the python kernel dies always on the following line:

```
# Load the original network and extract the fully connected layers' parameters.
net = caffe.Net('../models/deeplab/train.prototxt', 
                '../models/deeplab/train.caffemodel', 
                caffe.TRAIN)
```

I think its because pycaffe doesn't know their custom layers such as `ImageSegData`, `Silence` and `SegAccuracy` so I removed these layers from the prototxt file, but still the python kernel keeps on dying when I try to load the network model. Does anyone know how to load these weights into python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it already. I had literally to remove every custom layer and especially adapt the data layer such that it could read all the input images and thereby calculate the input dimensions.